# Нужно сдвинуть спрайт в анимации в Unity2D

Tags: unity3d

В чём проблема: у меня есть спрайты для всех анимаций персонажа и они в разрешении 64 на 64. Так же у меня есть анимация атаки, которая не влезает в разрешении 64 на 64, по этому оно в разрешение 128 на 128. Мне нужно каким - то образом сдвинуть в пространстве спрайт в анимации атаки так, что бы персонаж в атаке совпал со всеми остальными спрайтами. Объяснил криво, но может эта не менее кривая картинка меня спасёт. [image]